# How to improve SQL inner join performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How improve this query performance second table CustomerAccountBrand inner join
taking long time. I have added Non clustered index that is not use. Is this is split two inner join after that able concatenate?. Please any one help to get that data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    RA.AccountNumber, 
    RA.ShipTo,
    RA.SystemCode,
    CAB.BrandCode
FROM dbo.CustomerAccountRelatedAccounts RA  -- Views
INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerAccount CA
    ON RA.RelatedAccountNumber = CA.AccountNumber
    AND RA.RelatedShipTo = CA.ShipTo
    AND RA.RelatedSystemCode = CA.SystemCode 
INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerAccountBrand CAB   ---- Taking long time 4:30 mins
    ON  CA.AccountNumber = CAB.AccountNumber 
    AND CA.ShipTo = CAB.ShipTo 
    AND CA.SystemCode = CAB.SystemCode
```

---

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[CustomerAccountRelatedAccounts]
AS
SELECT        
    ca.AccountNumber, ca.ShipTo, ca.SystemCode, cafg.AccountNumber AS RelatedAccountNumber, cafg.ShipTo AS RelatedShipTo, 
    cafg.SystemCode AS RelatedSystemCode
FROM dbo.CustomerAccount AS ca 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CustomerAccount AS cafg 
        ON ca.FinancialGroup = cafg.FinancialGroup 
            AND ca.NationalAccount = cafg.NationalAccount
            AND cafg.IsActive = 1
WHERE CA.IsActive = 1
```

Comment: What is the definition of this non-clustered index?

Comment: Do you have a composite index on CA's and CAB's account number + ship to + system code? If not, you might want to test it on a dev/test server and see if that cuts down on your time. You might find value in adding same composite index on RA

Comment: How to create composite index?   It is working fine in my test/dev server but problem is prod server

Comment: Have you looked at the execution cost in Enterprise Manager to see where it's spending it's time?

Comment: I dont have access to see the Execution plan. Is this possible to modify the Script.

Comment: @Hasanshali It might be posible to see the execution plan cost without Enterprise Manager, but I don't know how. Sorry.

Comment: 1. How much data do you have in test/dev vs Prod in that view and table? 2.Check if indexes are same on dev and prod 3. Try updating stats on prod

Comment: Terry Carmen@ i will share Execution plan tomorrow.

Comment: Karthick@ CustomerAccountRelatedAccounts Views --- 8 million records and CustomerAccountBrand table 50 thousands

Comment: how long does just the select statement on view take? how many records does the first join get? can you share the script of your view? try creating a table variable with index on RelatedAccountNumber ,RelatedShipTo and RelatedSystemCode and copy content of view to it and join on that table variable

Comment: Why do you need to join with same table thrice (2 time in view and 1 in your query) can't you just use data coming from view?

Comment: views take 3 min but i split inner join it is taking 3 seconds see the query below
SELECT
 RA.AccountNumber, 
 RA.ShipTo,
 RA.SystemCode
FROM dbo.CustomerAccountRelatedAccounts RA
INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerAccount CA
 ON RA.RelatedAccountNumber = CA.AccountNumber
 AND RA.RelatedShipTo = CA.ShipTo
 AND RA.RelatedSystemCode = CA.SystemCode
GROUP BY RA.AccountNumber, 
 RA.ShipTo,
 RA.SystemCode

Comment: Views logic ------- One AccountNumber tied up with multiple account number that's why we used self join same table

Comment: You need to push back. Being asked to write queries and not having access to view the execution plan is stupid to new levels. Do you have multiple views here? There certainly seems to be some ways to improve performance in what I see what so far.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the SQL server query optimizer often fails to pick the correct join algorithm when queries become more complex (e.g. joining with your view means that there's no index readily available to join on). If that's what's happening here, then the easy fix is to add a join hint to turn it into a hash join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    RA.AccountNumber, 
    RA.ShipTo,
    RA.SystemCode,
    CAB.BrandCode
FROM dbo.CustomerAccountRelatedAccounts RA  -- Views
INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerAccount CA
    ON RA.RelatedAccountNumber = CA.AccountNumber
    AND RA.RelatedShipTo = CA.ShipTo
    AND RA.RelatedSystemCode = CA.SystemCode 
INNER HASH JOIN dbo.CustomerAccountBrand CAB   ---- Note the "HASH" keyword
    ON  CA.AccountNumber = CAB.AccountNumber 
    AND CA.ShipTo = CAB.ShipTo 
    AND CA.SystemCode = CAB.SystemCode
```